# How to solve stuttering audio output under ALSA?

Tags: alsa

One of App on a production HW system synthesizes audio commands from vocalizer plugin. From time to time - especially with longer sentences and/or high CPU load - audio is stuttering or loosing start/end of words. I don't have access to vocalizer binaries to tweak its configuration.

I thought about changing the ALSA configuration to add some buffering component to mitigate this.

Is this good approach? Are there anything better to use?

Comment: Have you considered PulseAudio or the even newer PipeWire? They come with additional CPU overhead and latency, but also with buffers which reduce stuttering.

Comment: No. This is commercial setup for one of our clients. We can't change ALSA to something else - doesn't matter how tempting it is.

Comment: PulseAudio and PipeWire do not replace ALSA. Rather, they sit between ALSA clients and the ALSA devices. I assumed that counted as a "buffering component".